# MySQL query error from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I've got the following query in my Java code. But when I run it, it says a syntax error in the query.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
"Inset into department ( dept_name, dept_desc ) values ('" + deptName + "','" + deptDesc + "')"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `INSERT` not `Inset` . This is a simple typo. Replace the word.

```
"Inset into department ( dept_name, dept_desc ) values ('" + deptName + "','" + deptDesc + "')"
 ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, as a beginner, using an [SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) might help point out the error for nagging issues like these.